# Save/Read Matrix from OpenCV FileNodeIterator

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having trouble saving and reading a `cv::Mat` saved into a `cv::FileNode` through which I am iterating. I can write the matrix to a file using

```
// Data to save
std::vector<cv::Mat> masks;
masks.push_back(cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8UC1));
masks.push_back(cv::Mat::zeros(2,2,CV_8UC1));

// Open file for writing
cv::FileStorage fs(file, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

// Create node
fs << "data" << "[";
for (size_t i=0; i<masks.size(); ++i)
{
    // Fill each node with data
    fs << "{:";
    // Write other data...
    fs << "mask" << masks.at(i);
    fs << "}";
}
fs << "]";
```

Writing a file in this way causes no problems. However, subsequently opening this file causes an unhandled exception which prints:

> Reading OpenCV Error: Parsing error (testPR.yml(7): Missing , between
>   the elemen ts) in unknown function, file
>   ......\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 12 63

To read the matrix I attempt to do this:

```
// Open file for reading
cv::FileStorage fs(file, cv::FileStorage::READ);   ///< This causes an exception

// Open node
cv::FileNode d = fs["data"];
cv::FileNodeIterator it = d.begin(), it_end = d.end();

for( ; it!= it_end; ++it)
{
    // Read other data...
    cv::Mat mask;
    (*it)["mask"] >> mask;
}
```

Surely it's possible to save/read a matrix to a node in this manner, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution to this was to save the data in an `.xml` rather than a `.yml` file, although I am none the wiser as to why that might be.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

> In YAML (but not XML), mappings and sequences can be written in a compact Python-like inline form. In the sample above matrix elements, as well as each feature, including its lbp value, is stored in such inline form. To store a mapping/sequence in a compact form, put ”:” after the opening character, e.g. use “{:” instead of “{“ and “[:” instead of “[“. When the data is written to XML, those extra ”:” are ignored.

Maybe **{:** can't be used without **[:**, but I couldn't find another documentation on this features. But regarding to your solution to store it in XML: The extra ":" is ignored...

From my opinion, storing to YAML should also work when deleting the ":".